# Feeding in the results of a FILTER as a criteria inside SUMIFS

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to perform a SUMIFS by using a FILTER (which can have multiple results) as the criteria for a criteria range inside the SUMIFS.

At the moment I have:

```
=SUMIFS(Unit18StockData!D:D,Unit18StockData!A:A=UNIQUE(FILTER(Raw_LG!D:D,Raw_LG!H:H=B2)))
```

However, this does not work. Essentially, the range in D:D should be summed for whenever the range A:A equals any of the results of the FILTER.

I tried to use ARRAYFORMULA as below but this gives zeros and in some cases errors:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Unit18StockData!A:A=UNIQUE(FILTER(Raw_LG!D:D,Raw_LG!H:H=B4)),Unit18StockData!D:D,0))
```

My formulae might look complicated due to the lengthy sheet names but ultimately I am just trying to pass a FILTER (that can have more than one result) as a criteria inside SUMIF.

Comment: Hi. Please share a [sample sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383) showing your expected input and output.

Comment: So the formula in column H of the "OOS Soon" sheet is what I am trying to get to work (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1voJxivwd1BhJjipGB7Y1zKPCm6KLwzerr8ctL1AGGE4/edit#gid=1104403476). If we take row 11 in this sheet as an example, I have broken the formula steps down in column K, L and M. You can see in column L that for that row's ASIN there are two EANs returned. The stock of each of these EANs is outlined in column M. However, in the SUMIF of column H, it only considers the first EAN as a criteria and not both EANs since the result of the SUMIF is 100 instead of the 100+300=400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try this for the `row_11 ASIN` Code (as in screenshot):*

```js
=sumifs(Unit18StockData!D:D,index(ifna(xmatch(Unit18StockData!A:A,unique(filter(Raw_LG!D:D,Raw_LG!H:H=B11)))^0)),1)
```

[image]